# How to use a dialog without buttons in glade and pygtk?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade, canonical-quickly

I'm using a platform called 'Quickly' in Ubuntu, basically it helps to make the base for view and programing, but my program needs to open a new window, and with Quickly I just can open a Dialog, but the dialogs with glade already have two buttons (Cancel, Ok), but, when I try to redesign the dialog it shows a message like;

> You can not delete a widget inside a compound widget.

I can't make a dialog just using pygtk because I don't have the helps of 'quickly' if I make it on the fly.

Thanks =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you use glade it let you create simple dialogs, and modify the action area, You can easily change the numbers of buttons and what you want them to say and how they are supposed bo behave.

Just play a bit more on with Glade, it sure let you build the Window/Dialog you want.